# map equivalent of a list comprehension not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax

I would like to rotate the tick labels in `matplotlib`. List comprehension works perfectly fine:

```
[tick.set_rotation(45) for tick in ax.get_xticklabels()]
```

However the equivalent code using `map` does not work:

```
map(lambda tick: tick.set_rotation(45), ax.get_xticklabels())
```

Nor:

```
map(operator.methodcaller('set_rotation', 45), ax.get_xticklabels())
```

What am I missing here?
I should note that the code using `map` compiles OK, but it does not rotate the tick lables.

Comment: What's not working?  What's the output you're seeing and what's the output you're expecting?

Comment: @payne, as mentioned the tick labels are not rotating

Comment: You should not be using a list comprehension or `map` for side-effects like this. Just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the code line

```
map(lambda tick: tick.set_rotation(45), ax.get_xticklabels())
```

works perfectly fine in python 2. This is because in python 2, `map` produces a list, effectively evaluating the mapping function for each element.

In python 3, `map` creates an instance of `map`, which is essentially an iterator, which does not get iterated through unless it needs to be.

So a solution for python 3 could be to create a `list` from the `map`,

```
list(map(lambda tick: tick.set_rotation(45), ax.get_xticklabels()))
```

The more idiomatic way would probably rather be to loop over the ticklabels,

```
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(45)
```

Taking into account how you'd usually rotate ticklabels in matplotlib, it would however rather be

```
 plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

or

```
 ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
```